# How to prove this identity about log and exp?

Tags: calculus, combinatorics, power-series

$$\sum_{k=1}^{m}\sum_{i_1+i_2+\dots+i_k=m}\left(\frac{1}{i_1!}\frac{1}{i_2!}\dots\frac{1}{i_k!}\right)\times\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k}=\begin{cases}1,& m=1\\ 0,& m>1\end{cases}$$
where $i_1,\dots,i_k$ are positive integers.

The motivation is to prove that $\log(\exp(x))=x$ in formal power series.

\begin{align*}
x=\log(e^x)=&\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}\frac{(e^{x}-1)^n}{n}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n+1}\frac{1}{n}(\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^m}{m!})^n                      \\
=&\sum_{m=1}^\infty \sum_{k=1}^{m}(\sum_{i_1+i_2+\dots+i_k=m}\left(\frac{1}{i_1!}\frac{1}{i_2!}\dots\frac{1}{i_k!}\right)\times\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k} )x^m
\end{align*}

Comment: There must be a typo in this, the $(-1)^{m+1}$ is wrong. [Otherwise for $m=2$ the LHS is negative and the RHS is $0$. ]

Comment: Sorry, $(-1)^{m+1}$ should be $(-1)^{k+1}$ @ancientmathematician

Comment: Exactly: so it's an inclusion-exclusion identity. Personally I think you should multiply the LHS by $m!$ and rewrite the factorials as the multinomial coefficient, that would make the structure of the identity more clear.

Comment: You should probably clarify that in the summation over tuples $(i_1,\dots,i_k)$ such that $i_1+\dots+i_k=m$, you are only considering tuples where $i_j\ge 1$ for each $j\in \{1,\dots,k\}$. P Quinton thought you were allowing zeroes, which led to their mistaken answer.

Answer (score 2):

We seek to show that

$$\sum_{k=1}^{m}\sum_{q_1+q_2+\dots+q_k=m}\left(\frac{1}{q_1!}
\frac{1}{q_2!}\cdots\frac{1}{q_k!}\right)
\times\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k}=\begin{cases}1,
& m=1\\ 0,& m>1\end{cases}$$

where $q_1,\dots,q_k$ are positive integers.

Write this as

$$\sum_{k=1}^{m} \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k}
\sum_{q_1+q_2+\cdots+q_k=m}
\frac{1}{q_1!}\frac{1}{q_2!}
\cdots\frac{1}{q_k!}.$$

We then get from first principles,

$$[w^m] \sum_{k=1}^m \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k}
(\exp(w)-1)^k
\\ = [w^m] \sum_{k=1}^m \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k}
\sum_{p=0}^k {k\choose p} \exp(pw) (-1)^{k-p}.$$

We may omit $p=0$ because with $m\ge 1$ there is no contribution to the
coefficient extractor:

$$[w^m] \sum_{k=1}^m \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k}
\sum_{p=1}^k {k\choose p} \exp(pw) (-1)^{k-p}
\\ = [w^m] \sum_{p=1}^m (-1)^{p+1} \exp(pw)
\sum_{k=p}^m \frac{1}{k} {k\choose p}
\\ = [w^m] \sum_{p=1}^m \frac{(-1)^{p+1}}{p} \exp(pw)
\sum_{k=p}^m {k-1\choose p-1}.$$

We have for the inner sum

$$\sum_{k=0}^{m-p} {k+p-1\choose p-1}
= [z^{m-p}] \frac{1}{1-z} \sum_{k\ge 0} {k+p-1\choose p-1} z^k
\\ = [z^{m-p}] \frac{1}{1-z} \frac{1}{(1-z)^p}
= [z^{m-p}] \frac{1}{(1-z)^{p+1}}
= {m\choose p}.$$

We thus obtain

$$[w^m] \sum_{p=1}^m \frac{(-1)^{p+1}}{p} \exp(pw) {m\choose p}
= \frac{1}{m} [w^{m-1}]
\sum_{p=1}^m (-1)^{p+1} \exp(pw) {m\choose p}.$$

We get two cases, first case $m=1$, which yields

$$ [w^0] (-1)^2 \exp(w) {1\choose 1} = 1 $$

as desired. For $m\gt 1$, second case, we may restore $p=0$ as we get no contribution to the coefficient extractor in that case:

$$\frac{1}{m} [w^{m-1}]
\sum_{p=0}^m (-1)^{p+1} \exp(pw) {m\choose p}
\\ = - \frac{1}{m} [w^{m-1}] (1-\exp(w))^m = 0$$

because

$$(1-\exp(w))^m = (-1)^m w^m + \cdots.$$

This concludes the argument.

Answer (score 1):

**[Multinomial Theorem :](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem)** For $i_1+i_2+\dots+i_k=m$, let ${m\choose i_1~\dots~i_k}=\frac{m!}{i_1!\dots i_k!}$ be the multinomial coefficients, then the following generalizes Newton's Binomial's Theorem
\begin{align*}
(x_1+\dots+x_k)^m=\sum_{i_1+\dots+i_k=m} {m\choose i_1~\dots~i_k}\prod_{j=1}^k x_j^{i_j}
\end{align*}

This can be proven by induction on $k$ from the binomial theorem (which can be proven by induction on $m$).

Using this you get
\begin{align*}
&\sum_{k=1}^m \sum_{i_1+\dots+i_k=m} \frac{1}{m!}{m\choose i_1~\dots~i_k}\times \frac{(-1)^{m+1}}{k}\\
=&\sum_{k=1}^m  \frac{1}{m!}\times \frac{(-1)^{m+1}}{k}\sum_{i_1+\dots+i_k=m}{m\choose i_1~\dots~i_k}1^{i_1}\dots 1^{i_k}\\
=&\sum_{k=1}^m  \frac{1}{m!}\times \frac{(-1)^{m+1}}{k}k^m\\
=&\frac{(-1)^{m+1}}{m!}\sum_{k=1}^m k^{m-1}
\end{align*}

As mentionned by @ancientmathematician, this will not lead to what your want but shows you a way to use the multinomial Theorem for such cases.

Comment: [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4488730/composition-of-formal-power-series-of-exp-and-log) is something similar to my question. But this is about exp(log x)=x.

Comment: This answer is mistaken, even after correcting the mistake pointed out in ancientmathematician's comment. The $\sum_{i_1+\dots+i_k=m}$ summation only ranges over tuples $(i_1,\dots,i_k)$ whose entries are positive integers. You need to sum over all nonnegative integer tuples to use the multinomial theorem.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to prove $\log \exp x = x$ as an identity of formal power series is to take derivatives. Observe that we have $\frac{d}{dx} \log \left( 1 + x \right) = \frac{1}{1 + x}$ (as an identity of formal power series) and $\frac{d}{dx} \exp(x) = \exp(x)$; the formal chain rule then gives

$$\frac{d}{dx} \log \exp x = \frac{1}{\exp(x)} \exp(x) = 1$$

from which it follows that $\log \exp x = x$ after plugging in $x = 0$ to verify that the constant term is correct. In the middle technically we are writing the above expression as $\log (1 + (\exp x - 1))$ to keep everything in the realm of formal power series.

Comment: Since [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4488730/composition-of-formal-power-series-of-exp-and-log) problem which proves exp(log x)=x in formal power series mentioned unsigned Stirling number of the first kind, I want to know the explanation of this identity through combination method. However, your approach is also elegant.